# Why is int the same size as long in C?

Tags: c, int, long-integer

Perhaps better question is, how is it possible that long can store larger numbers than integer, when my compiler tells me that `sizeof(int)` = `sizeof(long)` = 4 bytes? I can't wrap my head around it...why wouldn't there be an overflow? Is it adjusted during runtime when there is a need for larger numbers?

Comment: In C, the size of types such as `int` and `long` can be different on different systems. If `int` and `long` have the same number of bits on your system, then it is not true that `long` can store larger numbers than `int`.

Comment: For C99 (and later) you can try `long long` or [`<stdint.h>` types](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html): `int_least32_t`, `int_least64_t`

Comment: The problem is your assumption that `long` can store larger numbers than `int`. That's not necessarily the case.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types):

The standard mandates that `int` is *at least* 16 bit, and `long` is at least 32 bit. So depending on the implementation, it's possible that they're the same size (they could both be 32 bit), or they could be of different sizes. This means that the same program compiled for two different environments may behave differently if it makes assumptions about the size of those data types.

> why wouldn't there be an overflow? Is it adjusted during runtime when
>   there is a need for larger numbers?

If for instance you add two integers and store the result in a `long`, there could indeed be overflow if the `long` has the same size as the `int`. That's the problem with those types not having a guaranteed size. If you need such a guarantee, use types like `int32_t` and `int64_t` instead, those are guaranteed to be 32 respectively 64 bit.